# Access SQL Server 2008 R2 via Scala/JDBC on Windows 2008 64 bit using integrated authentication

Tags: sql-server, scala, jdbc

I'm trying to access a SQL server 2008 using scala without any success. Here is my sample code:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); 
val connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=XXX;integratedSecurity=true;";
val con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
```

And here is the error I get:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1352)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1339)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(IOBuffer.java:1654)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:3694)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:5026)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:4978)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2528)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:1905)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1893)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4575)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1045)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:817)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

I have no idea what's going wrong and I'm not able to get any further debug output. What I have checked is the following:

- Sql server is up and running of course and can be accessed from Management Studio or via .Net Code.
- I have 64bit Java installed and I'm using the 64bit sqljdbc_auth.dll. I gave the 32bit version a try (just to be sure) and got the expected error, telling me to use the 64bit version.
- If I remove the integratedSecurity=true from the connection string, I get the expected authentication error from SQL server: Login failed for user ''.

Obviously the integrated authentication is the problem. Any hint how to fix that or how to debug any further?

Comment: Did you consider passing the username and password?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention: Username/password is not an option.

Comment: Did you work this out? What did SQL Server log say, it should give an indication.

Answer (score 0):

This [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx) suggests that you have to copy a file, or change a path:

> To use integrated authentication, copy the sqljdbc_auth.dll file to a
>   directory on the Windows system path on the computer where the JDBC
>   driver is installed.

Under the "Connecting with Integrated Authentication" section.

Answer (score 0):

I've had more success using the jTDS open source driver to access SQL Server databases through JDBC (http://jtds.sourceforge.net/).

I used this to connect to a SQL Server 2008 instance using this connection URL:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/DatabaseName;instance=InstanceName
```

My connection still seems to work when I add the property `integratedSecurity=True`, but it doesn't seem necessary.  I believe the jTDS docs say that you're not supposed to end the connection URL with a semi-colon.

You'll have to add the `ntmlauth.dll` file to your JRE/JDK `/bin` directory.  **You also must ensure that the SQL Server Browser service is running.  My understanding is that this is true both for the jTDS driver and the Microsoft driver (run the SQL Server Configuration Manager and star the SQL Server Browser service.  You may want to set it to automatically start on startup).**

Another nice advantage of jTDS is that you can get it through a Maven repository if you're using Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```